# How to reset the QLabel content when clicked on QPushButton in PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have provided the sample code of my complete code to give you an overview. In this code, when am clicking the button multiple times the content of QLabel gets appended. What I need is whenever I click on the QPushButton previous content should be cleard out and only new content gets loaded.

```
def _func1():
self.button = QPushButton('Search')
self.button.clicked.connect(self.validateentries)   
self.vert_layout_final = QVBoxLayout(self)
self.setLayout(self.vert_layout_final)

self.label = QLabel()

self.label.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
self.label.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
self.label.setStyleSheet("QLabel#nom_plan_label {color: yellow}")

self.scroll = QScrollArea()
self.scroll.setWidget(self.label)
self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
self.scroll.setFixedHeight(250)

self.vert_layout_final.addWidget(self.scroll)

def validateentries(self):
    self.label.setText("Hello")
    self.parent().set_status_message("Searching..")
    text1 = getval()
    self.label.setText(text1)


#Actual code has logic to process and return dynamic content
def getval:
    text = "Text 1"#Changes everytime
    return text
```

Comment: `QLabel.setText(new_text)` should clear the previous text.

Comment: No, it is appending to the existing text.

Comment: @surajsabat No, it doesn't: `setText()` **always** clears the previous text. If it does not in your case, there's something wrong elsewere in the code you're not showing us. Please provide a [minimal, **reproducible** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and read [how to format your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) so that it's readable and we can easily copy, paste and run it.

Comment: Yes, you were right. There was a mistake in my coding, I was getting the text value from a method declared in different class. The variable where I was storing the text value was a global variable due which the old value was getting retained on multiple invocation unless the application is restarted.